# React's Hook set function won't update array on submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
export default function App() {

     const [arrayOne, setArrayOne] = useState([{name: 'A', age: 10, 
                                       hobbies: [{name: soccer, experience: 12}]}, 
                                      {name: 'B', age: 6, hobbies: []}])
     const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
     const [newAge, setNewAge] = useState(0)

     function handleSubmit(e) {
         e.preventDefault()
         const newEntry = {name: newName, age: newAge, hobbies: []}
         setArrayOne([newEntry, ...arrayOne])
         console.log(arrayOne)
     }

     return(

        <div>
            <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
                  <input type="text" value={newName} onChange={e => setNewName(e.target.value)} />
                  <input type="number" value={newAge} onChange={e => setNewAge(e.target.value)} />
                  <input type="submit />
            </form>
        </div>

     )

}
```

For some reason arrayOne won't update after submit is pressed on the form, it always lags behind one submit click. Is there anyway I can make it so it updates immediately?

Comment: It doesn't look like `arrayOne` is being used anywhere?

Comment: how did you check arrayOne after submit?

Comment: Your code looks correct to me.

Comment: It [works fine for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-mayer-u96vd?file=/src/App.tsx) when adding a submit button inside the form.

Comment: Hmm, that is very weird. Mines is constantly lagging one entry behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
let copiedArray = [... arrayOne];

copiedArray.push(newEntry);

setArrayOne(copiedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `setArrayOne((curr) => [...curr, newEntry])`